# How to make Functions.makeHTTPrequest call in Reactjs application and pass that same React component as a string in executeRequest smart contract Call

Tags: chainlink

How do I make a post request similar like above in a ReactJs application and pass the same as a string while calling the executeRequest function in FunctionConsumer.sol?

```
const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: 'myApi.com',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    args: ['Hey', 'Hi'],
  },
  headers: 'Content-Type: application/json',
});

const { data } = apiResponse;

console.log('API response data:', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Also, how can I call the API using fetch API and pass that react component as a string in `executeRequest` function call, below is my react fetch API call to the API

```
export const handleSubmitt = async () => {
 
  const args = ['PLeaselast', 'Try'];
  const request = await fetch(
    'myApi.com',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ args }),
    }
  );
  const data = await request.json();
  console.log(data);
};
```

Comment: Hi Kenil, Why do you want to use `Functions.makeHttpRequest` in your Reactjs application?

Comment: Hey @FrankKong yes, as of now I passed my api as a string to the executeRequest function for workaround but would love to hear from you